# Displaying results of perform find in a portal

Tags: find, portal, filemaker

I have some global variables `$$A`, `$$B`, `$$C` and what to search within a table for these terms in `fieldA`, `fieldB` and `fieldC` (using Perform Find). How can I use the result of this Perform Find to display the results in a portal.

*The implementation by my predecessor replaces a field `fieldSEARCH`with 1 if it is in the Perform Find results and 0 otherwise, and then uses a portal filtered by this field. This seems a very dodgey way of doing it, not least becuase it means that multiple users will not be able to search at the same time!*

Comment: I basically want to do Perform Find within Filter Portal Results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you enhance the portal filter to filter against the variables themselves? Or you can perform the find, grab IDs of the found set, put them into a global field, and then use the field to construct the relationship. Global fields are multi-user safe.

The best way is not to do this at all, but use list views to perform searches. List views are naturally searchable and much more flexible than portals (you can easily sort them, omit arbitrary records, and so on). It's possible to repeat this functionality in portals, but it's way more complex. I mean, if there's some serious gain from using a portal, then it's doable, but if not, then the native way is obviously better.

Comment: thanks for this. I had been trying to make long filtering with global variables, but it is not working particularly well. List views sound promising!

Answer (score 0):

List views are easier to search, as FileMaker still hasn't transitioned to the 21st century and insists on this model... Most users however want a Master-Detail view, like a mail app, and understandably so as it's more intuitive (i.e. produce a list view on one side, but clicking on it updates detail/fields in the middle).

If this is what you want, you may want to cast an eye at Modular FM, where someone has already done the hard work for you:
http://www.modularfilemaker.org/module/masterdetail-2-0/

HTH
Stam